# Xamarin Forms Bindings not showing on Page

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding

I am facing a strange problem and i don't know why this happens. I have created an `AccountPage` showing the `Username`, `Name` and a `Description` which i bound from the viewmodel. The App checks whether a token exists and pushes a `LoginPage` if there is no token.

If i now push the create Account Page from the `Loginpage` and create an account i get popped back to the Account page. Although the `OnAppearing` Method on the `AccountPage` gets called and the Bindings have the correct values in the VM there is nothing shown in the view. When i close the app and restart it, however, i can see the values of the Bindings on the View. How does this happen and how can i fix this?

the AccoountPage:

```
    ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:DoggoApp.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:AccountPageViewModel"
             BindingContext="AccountPageViewModel"
             Title="{Binding Username}"
             BackgroundColor="#FBFDFB"
             x:Class="DoggoApp.Views.AccountPage"> 
    
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.27*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.7*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
                <Frame  CornerRadius="100" Padding="0" Margin="25" IsClippedToBounds="True">
                    <Image Source="default_user.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill" Scale="0.44" Margin="-60"/>
                </Frame>
                <StackLayout Margin="10,40">
                    <Label Text=""/>
                    <Label Text="Beiträge"
                           Style="{StaticResource AccountPage}"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Margin="10,40">
                    <Label Text=""/>
                    <Label Text="Follower"
                           Style="{StaticResource AccountPage}"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Margin="10,40">
                    <Label Text=""/>
                    <Label Text="Following"
                           Style="{StaticResource AccountPage}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Margin="15,-20">
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" Style="{StaticResource AccountPage}"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Description}" Style="{StaticResource AccountPage}"/>
                <Frame Padding="0,15">
                    <Button Text="Edit Profile" Margin="-20" Clicked="EditAccount_Clicked"/>
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
```

code behind:

```
namespace DoggoApp.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class AccountPage : ContentPage
    {
        
        
        private static AccountPageViewModel accountPageViewmodel;
        public AccountPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = accountPageViewmodel = new AccountPageViewModel();

        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            accountPageViewmodel.NotRefreshTokenAction = (async (obj) =>
            {
                await DisplayAlert("DoggoApp", "Please log in again", "Ok");
            });
            base.OnAppearing();
            
            bool LoggedIn = await accountPageViewmodel.Login();
            if (!LoggedIn)
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
                return;
            }
            
        }
```

the viewmodel:

```
    public partial class AccountPageViewModel : ObservableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {



        // == constants ==
        private static readonly IAccountService accountService = DependencyService.Get<IAccountService>();
        private static readonly ISaveService saveService = DependencyService.Get<ISaveService>();
        // == observable Properties ==

        private string username;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private string name;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private string description;

        public string Username
        {
            get { return username; }
            set
            {
                username = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Username));
            }
        }

        public Action<bool> NotRefreshTokenAction { get; set; }

        // == Relay Commands ==
        [RelayCommand]
        public async Task<bool> Login()
        {
            try
            {
                bool refreshed = await accountService.RefreshToken();
                    
                if(refreshed)
                {
                    AccountDto dto = await accountService.GetDisplayAccount();
                    Username = dto.username;
                    Name = dto.name;
                    Description = dto.description;
                    return true;
                }
                throw new Exception("refreshed was false");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string message = ex.Message;
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                return false;
            }
            
        }
```

Create Account VM:

```
    namespace DoggoApp.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class CreateAccountPage : ContentPage
    {
        private static CreateAccountViewModel createAccountViewModel;
        public CreateAccountPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = createAccountViewModel = new CreateAccountViewModel();
            createAccountViewModel.AccountCreatedAction = (async (obj) =>
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Doggoapp", "Registration Successfull", "Ok");
                await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I‘m not quite sure because I might need your more detailed code and Install packages information. And you may try  to change "BindingContext = accountPageViewmodel = new AccountPageViewModel(); " to "accountPageViewmodel=this. BindingContext".

Comment: I retract my original view. You may try to change "await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());" to "await Navigation.PushAsync(new AccoountPage());" for trying.